# Increasing scrollable content height (from top)

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview

What I want to do is increase the size of the scrollable content of my UIScrollView programatically (every time a button is pressed, UILabel is made and stacked one on top of another on scrollView), and add the extra height to the top of my current ScrollView, so that I can scroll further up (rather than further down).

I have actually figured out how to add more scrollable content space to my scroll view:

```
var contentRect = CGRect.zero
for view in scrollView.subviews {
    contentRect = contentRect.union(view.frame)
}
scrollView.contentSize = contentRect.size
```

However, the extra space being added to the scroll view is at the bottom of the scroll view, when I want it to be at the top (so that I can scroll further up). Is there any way I can do this? Hopefully this makes sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't add the extra height to the top. After increasing the size of `contentSize`, you need to update the frame of each view in the scroll view to shift them down.

Another option would be to use a UIStackView or UITableView which support adding additional view/rows.